# How can I create a “glow” around a Path without using a filter in svg?

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I used This code :

```
<defs>
            <filter id="lineshadow">
                <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#0F0" flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
                <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="color-out"></feComposite>
                <feGaussianBlur result="color-out" stdDeviation="1" in="mask"></feGaussianBlur>
                <feOffset in="shadow" dx="0" dy="0" result="color-out"></feOffset>
                <feMerge>
                    <feMergeNode in="drop-shadow"></feMergeNode>
                    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
                </feMerge>
            </filter>
        </defs>
```

But don't need filter because its not working on older version of chromium .
Is any other option for create a “glow” around a line.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you talking about?  SVG filters have been supported since at least Chrome 10. Current Chrome is v46.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could try something like this.

```html
<svg>

  <g stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round">

    <!-- the glow -->
    <line x1="50" y1="75" x2="250" y2="75" stroke-width="30" stroke-opacity="0.02"/>
    <line x1="50" y1="75" x2="250" y2="75" stroke-width="20" stroke-opacity="0.05"/>
    <line x1="50" y1="75" x2="250" y2="75" stroke-width="12" stroke-opacity="0.1"/>
    <line x1="50" y1="75" x2="250" y2="75" stroke-width="8" stroke-opacity="0.25"/>
    <line x1="50" y1="75" x2="250" y2="75" stroke-width="6" stroke-opacity="0.5"/>

    <!-- the black line -->
    <line x1="50" y1="75" x2="250" y2="75" stroke-width="4" stroke="black"/>
    
  </g>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: But my line is shown like :




<path d="M348.0592500306344,157.41994496095526L378.33222976696254,394.5582811425959" data-bindattr-1345="1345" stroke="#000" data-bindattr-1346="1346" stroke-dasharray="0" data-bindattr-1347="1347" stroke-width="0.3" data-bindattr-1348="1348" marker-start="none" data-bindattr-1349="1349" marker-end="none" data-bindattr-1350="1350" flag="line" data-bindattr-1351="1351" fill="none" data-bindattr-1352="1352" class="" data-bindattr-1353="1353"></path>

Comment: Just replace my `<line>` with your `<path>`. Just keep the `stroke-width` and `stroke-opacity` attributes.

Comment: And i want it dynamically  and i m using d3